# Preserve visual order of mixed floated elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

**JSFiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/ttpkfs9s/

I have a UI component that should arrange elements into a row and displays them with elements on the left and on the right, with the active element being in the middle:

`[1][2][3]   [4]   [5][6][7][8][9]`

So far I have been achieving this by floating elements `left` and `right`, while keeping the one in the middle `float: none;` (this is good enough).

However, way too late into implementing the navigation JS I realised that I've made a huge mistake, and that the actual order the elements are displayed in are as follows:

`[1][2][3]   [4]   [9][8][7][6][5]`

Which is a huge problem as these elements are supposed to be clickable /facepalm

Are there any at most not too invasive CSS/HTML options I can use to get the displayed order correct?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I missed the part about you needing the active div to always be in the center of the row.

You could contain the div's inside a container, and float the container insted, but that would probably be hard to do.

I took the liberty of changing things up abit, maybe you can use it, maybe u can't.

I set all items to the same width, and made a function for resizing the div's after u click one of the items.

https://jsfiddle.net/ttpkfs9s/1/

html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="item left">1</div>
<div class="item left">2</div>
<div class="item left">3</div>
<div class="item left">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
<div class="item">7</div>
<div class="item">8</div>
<div class="item">9</div>
<div class="item">10</div>
```

css

```
.row {
height: 150px;
background: blue;
width: 100%;
}

.item {
float: left;
padding: 2.5px;
color: white;
width: 9.4%;
height: 100%;
background: red;
margin: 0 0.3%;
box-sizing: border-box;
transition: 0.7s linear;
}

.active {
color: black;
background: yellow;
}
```

js

```
function setWidth(){
if($(".item").hasClass("active")){
    $(".item").width("6%");
    $(".active").width("40%");
};
}

$(".item").click(function(){
$(".item").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");

setWidth();
})
```